# Create pixel from camera given byte in android

Tags: android, pixel

I have an OCR scanning text logic that needs to work in **real-time**. The app needs to scan any text that appears on the camera.

Currently I'm grabbing the `onPreviewFrame` method of the camera and for accurateness I want to convert the byte data which gives me that method to pixel.

How do i do it? As so far in google i could not find my answer.

So far i just tried this code and nothing else because nothing else i could find

```
 Pix pix = Pix.createFromPix(byteData,imageWidth,imageHeight,imageDepth);
```

but i have feeling im doing wrong and this is not pixel formating from byte...

Comment: Please add any code you have tried so far.

Comment: You did not tell what kind of image format is in 'byte[]data'.

Comment: ok i have edited the code and byte[]data can not have any format unless i specify it.......so yeah no kind of image as byte is an array of not ready images and byte can actually be anything and not only image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description of [onPreviewFrame()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html#onPreviewFrame(byte[],%20android.hardware.Camera)), the content of the bytes depends on the previously set preview format. If you set the format to [RAW10](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#RAW10) for example, its documentation says:

> In an image buffer with this format, starting from the first pixel of
>   each row, each 4 consecutive pixels are packed into 5 bytes (40 bits).

The documentation explains quite in detail how you can get all the pixels.

However, I should think converting the bytes this way **might be too slow if implemented in Java**, especially if you want real time. The camera provides methods to show preview images constantly in a SurfaceView, but as far as I know you cannot grab a bitmap from there either.

I should have a look at the source code of the [xzing barcode scanner project](https://github.com/zxing/zxing). They do realtime detection of various bar codes, so you should be able to extract the image taking part from there.